# Double line for header/footer rules

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, rules, exam

I want to create a fancy header/footer rule in Exam document class. I have tried what is at [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89569/custom-header-footer-rules-fancyhdr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89423/two-rules-directly-under-each-other) and [Custom header/footer rules (fancyhdr?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89569/custom-header-footer-rules-fancyhdr) but they seem not to work in Exam document class. Any help please

Answer (score 3):

`exam.cls` uses its own mechanism for headers/footers. To modify the default rules in headers, you can patch `\@fullhead` (for the first page) and `\run@fullhead` (for other pages) to use whatever you choose, instead of the default `\hrule`. A little example using a double rule:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@fullhead}{\hrule}{\hrule\vskip2pt\hrule height 2pt}{}{}
\patchcmd{\run@fullhead}{\hrule}{\hrule\vskip2pt\hrule height 2pt}{}{}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\runningheadrule
\firstpageheadrule
\firstpageheader{Math 115}{First Exam}{July 4, 1776}
\runningheader{Math 115}
{First Exam, Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
{July 4, 1776}
\firstpagefooter{}{}{}
\runningfooter{}{}{}

\begin{document}
test\clearpage
test
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the case of footers, one has to patch `\@fullfoot` and `\run@fullfoot` and invoke `\runningfootrule`, `\firstpagefootrule`.

Comment: Thanks @Gonzalo. It is exactly what I want and I have done it for the footers as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @NanaYaw You're welcome! Please, if you consider my answer solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).