# Change line color and thickness and line spacing

Tags: color, line-spacing, resume

I am new to LaTeX and I am creating a resume.

I have added a black line.

1)However, I would like to know how to specify a color and line thickness for this line?

2) I would like to know how to adjust line spacing? I know I can use `\setspace`. I am not too happy with `\singlespacing` and `onehalfspacing`. I am looking for something in between these 2.  I want to be able to manually adjust the line spacing (is there a parameter that I can set?).

3) For the last row, I am trying to do `tab` then "Sixth Form" but I do not understand why latex is not allowing me to do it ?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} 
\usepackage[top=0.7in, left=0.3in, bottom=0.0in, right=0.3in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\singlespacing

\oddsidemargin=0.0in 
\evensidemargin=0.0in 
\textwidth=6.5in 
\marginparwidth=0.5in
\headheight=0pt 
\headsep=0pt 
\textheight=9.0in 
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}
\centerline{\huge \bf My Name}
\vspace{2.5pt}
\centerline{$\bullet$ Address $\bullet$ (Country code)phone number}
\centerline{Email}
\noindent{\LARGE \bf Education} \\
{\line(1,0){475}}
\hspace{10in}{Sixth Form } \hfill{Time}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Line spacing and thickness of the rule are totally unrelated, so perhaps best to separate this into two questions.  Also [Two rules directly under each other](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89423/two-rules-directly-under-each-other) and [What is the \rule equivalent for \hrule?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17124/what-is-the-rule-equivalent-for-hrule) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\setstretch{..}` to set a different factor, although in general changing the baseline from the one intended in the font design usually doesn't lead to an improvement.

Other comments, you loaded the `geometry` package (usually the best way of setting page dimensions) but then over-rode all its settings by setting lower level LaTeX parameters:

```
\oddsidemargin=0.0in 
\evensidemargin=0.0in 
\textwidth=6.5in 
\marginparwidth=0.5in
\headheight=0pt 
\headsep=0pt 
\textheight=9.0in
```

---

```
\centerline{\huge \bf My Name}
\vspace{2.5pt}
```

`\centerline` and `\bf` shouldn't really be used in LaTeX they are hang overs from plain TeX (`\bf` is not even defined by default, just added as a compatibility layer by the document class).  Whenever you have a font size change it is best to include a paragraph end (`\par` or blank line) within the same scope, otherwise you set large text on a small baseline.

Similarly

```
\noindent{\LARGE \bf Education} \\
```

Avoid `\\` except in tabular etc. This should be

```
{\LARGE\textbf{Education}\par}
```

`\line` is only intended fro picture mode, I was surprised it didn't give an explicit error here but apparently not. Use `\rule`

```
{\line(1,0){475}}
```

Should be

```
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}\par
```

Or to change the width and colour

add

```
\usepackage{color}
```

then

```
\noindent\textcolor{red}{\rule{\textwidth}{5pt}}\par
```

Comment: How can i set the length of `\rule` ?

Comment: @asd the first parameter of `\rule` I used `\textwidth` but you can make it 6in or 0.5\textwith or ....

Comment: what unit of measurement is 0.5 ? is it in inch or pt ?

Comment: @asd This is standard LaTeX syntax, across all commands taking lengths, perhaps you should start with a tutorial such as `lshort` which is available in all tex distributions. `.5\textwidth` is half of `\textwidth` ie half the width of the printed area. You can not use `0.5` units have to be explicit.