# Center text between double horizontal rules

Tags: rules

I'd like to do something like this:

```
====================   Text   ====================
```

Where '===' represents two horizontal lines separated by 2pt. In other words, I'd like to center some text between double horizontal lines. I have found a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243651/center-text-between-horizontal-lines-extending-to-the-margin-on-either-side) and attempted to adapt the following solution by egreg:

```
\newcommand{\textbetweenrules}[2][.4pt]{%
  \par\vspace{\topsep}
  \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
    \sbox0{#2}%
    \dimen0=.5\dimexpr\ht0+#1\relax
    \dimen2=-.5\dimexpr\ht0-#1\relax
    \leaders\hrule height \dimen0 depth \dimen2\hfill
    \quad #2\quad
    \leaders\hrule height \dimen0 depth \dimen2\hfill
  }\par\nopagebreak\vspace{\topsep}
}
```

And combine it with the solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89423/two-rules-directly-under-each-other) for making double rules:

```
\hrule width \hsize \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize
```

However, no matter what I try, the second \hrule doesn't seem to be recognized properly and I either get "height depth" printed on my document or nothing at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\textbetweenrules}[2][.4pt]{%
  \par\vspace{\topsep}
  \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
    \sbox0{#2}%
    \dimen0=.5\dimexpr\ht0+#1\relax
    \dimen2=-.5\dimexpr\ht0-#1\relax
    \leaders\hrule height \dimen0 depth \dimen2 \kern2pt \hrule height \dimen0 depth \dimen2\hfill
    \quad #2\quad
    \leaders\hrule height \dimen0 depth \dimen2 \kern2pt \hrule height \dimen0 depth \dimen2\hfill\hfill
  }\par\nopagebreak\vspace{\topsep}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\textbetweenrules{Text}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the same idea, but leaders don't work here, so I prepare a vbox with the double rules after computing their width.

Somewhat arbitrarily, the space between the rules is four times their thickness.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\textbetweendoublerules}[2][.4pt]{%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
    \sbox0{\quad#2\quad}%
    \dimen0=.5\dimexpr\ht0+#1\relax
    \dimen2=-.5\dimexpr\ht0-#1\relax
    \dimen4=.5\dimexpr\textwidth-\wd0\relax
    \setbox2=\vbox to \ht0{%
      \vss
      \hrule width \dimen4 height #1
      \kern 4\dimexpr#1\relax
      \hrule width \dimen4 height #1
      \vss
    }%
    \copy2 \box0 \box2
  }\par\nopagebreak\addvspace{\topsep}%
}

\begin{document}

\textbetweendoublerules{abc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm. I only changed '4\dimexpr#1' to '2pt' to be consistent with other double rules in my document.  Thanks for also helping me understand what all the dimension commands stand for.

Answer (score 5):

I would go a different route and place the text in a coloured box over the lines. This way you don't have to worry about the centering.

*(The code below is just a prove of concept, please adjust the lengths to your needs)*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\textbetweenrules}[1]{%
    \begin{center}
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0.4cm}
        \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\\[-0.3cm]
        \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\\[-0.65cm]
        \colorbox{white}{#1}
    \end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\textbetweenrules{Text}

\lipsum[2]

\textbetweenrules{longer text text text}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure there are 2pt between the lines?

Comment: @TeXnician No. I just used dummy numbers. I will mention this in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

It might be overkill to load Ti*k*Z for that, but if you load it anyway, you might consider this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand{\RuleText}[1]{%
\centerline{\tikz{\draw[double,line width=1pt,double distance between line
centers=3pt] (0,0)--(\linewidth,0) node[midway,fill=white]{#1};}}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\RuleText{koala bear}

\lipsum[2]

\RuleText{marmot}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's one version which is quite "hacky", but at least works for short text. You would have to play around with the vskips to get 2pt distance.

[image: lines]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\textbetweenlines[1]{%
    \par
    \vskip-.2\baselineskip
    \noindent\hrulefill\phantom{\quad#1\quad}\hrulefill\par
    \vskip-.8\baselineskip
    \noindent\hrulefill\quad%
    \raisebox{-.1\baselineskip}{#1}\quad\hrulefill%
    \par
    \vskip.1\baselineskip
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\textbetweenlines{Test}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```