# Spacing between horizontal lines in a title and spacing in general

Tags: spacing, titles, line-spacing

I am trying to create a custom title for my document, but the space between my horizontal lines, or the spacing in general doesn't work properly.
Here is a **minimal-working-example**, which - I hope - yields more clarity:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,DIV=15, ngerman]{scrartcl}  % parskip=half or parskip=full
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{lmodern}


\newcommand{\mytitle}{
        \textsf{
            \begin{center}
                \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt} % Thick horizontal rule
                \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt} % Thin horizontal rule
                \vspace{0.75\baselineskip} % Whitespace above the title
                \Large \textbf{Wonderfull Title} \\ %\vspace{0.3cm}
                \large\textbf{Here stands a great Subtitle}
                \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt} % Thin horizontal rule
                \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt} % Thick horizontal rule
                \vspace{2\baselineskip} % Whitespace after the title block
                Last compiled on \textbf{Date} \\
                von \textbf{Author}\\
            \end{center}
        }
}

\begin{document}
    \mytitle
    
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

**The result is:**
[image]

**The problems are:**

- The spacing between the bottom lines seems like intended, but between the top lines, there is too much space, despite it beeing exactly the same code
- Between the Subtitle and the two bottom lines, there is too much space
- Between the Date and the author is way too much space

**My Questions regarding this topic are:**

1. Why is the spacing as it is? What is Latexs intention? I would like to understand the inner workings of tex better.
2. How can my concrete problems with spacing be solved?
3. What are the best practises for creating a good looking title?

(Of course I am happy to get any input, f.e. for better practises in latex in general -  it doesn't have to directly answer the questions)

Thank you for your answers in advance!

P.S.: This is my first post on this forum so please criticize me constructively! I am really unsure, how to express myself in the most clear way.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem was the `\Large` and `\large` affecting the baseline skips. Use `{` and `}` to limit their scope.

After that it is easy to control the vertical spaces between the elements.

Regarding the two parallel lines, see the useful example in [Drawing close together horizontal lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/478832/161015)

For inspiration look the nice titles in [nice title pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85904/showcase-of-beautiful-title-page-done-in-tex)

As an example on how to design a cover or a title page according to strict specifications see
[Tschichold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44258/161015)

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,DIV=15, ngerman]{scrartcl}  % parskip=half or parskip=full
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{lmodern}


\newcommand{\mytitle}{%
        \textsf{%
        \centering
        \hrule height 1.6pt depth 0pt width \textwidth
        \vspace{2pt}
        \hrule height 0.4pt depth 0pt width \textwidth
        \bigskip
        {\bfseries \Large Wonderfull Title} \\ \vspace{0.3cm}
        {\bfseries \large Here stands a great Subtitle} \\\vspace{10pt}
        \hrule height 0.4pt depth 0pt width \textwidth
        \vspace{2pt}
        \hrule height 1.6pt depth 0pt width \textwidth
        \vspace{\baselineskip} % Whitespace after the title block
        Last compiled on \textbf{Date} \\ \vspace{0.3cm}
        von \textbf{Author}\\
        \vspace*{3\baselineskip}    
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \mytitle
    
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Finally, to protect the template and ensure consistency when used repeatedly, define a command with  four mandatory parameters:

```
\newcommand{\mytitle}[4]{% four mandatory parameters
\textsf{%
    \centering
    \hrule height 1.6pt depth 0pt width \textwidth
    \vspace{2pt}
    \hrule height 0.4pt depth 0pt width \textwidth
    \bigskip
    {\bfseries \Large #1} \\ \vspace{0.3cm}
    {\bfseries \large #2} \\\vspace{10pt}
    \hrule height 0.4pt depth 0pt width \textwidth
    \vspace{2pt}
    \hrule height 1.6pt depth 0pt width \textwidth
    \vspace{\baselineskip} % Whitespace after the title block
    Last compiled on \textbf{#3} \\ \vspace{0.3cm}
    von \textbf{#4}\\
    \vspace*{3\baselineskip}    
        }
    }
```

And use as  `\mytitle{Wonderfull Title}{Here stands a great Subtitle}{Date}{Author}`

Comment: Thank you very much! This was really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt} % Thin horizontal rule
\vspace{0.75\baselineskip} % Whitespace above the title
\Large \textbf{Wonderfull Title}
```

Then a rule is added in horizontal mode, then still in horizontal mode the space .75 of the current baselineskip is stored away to be added after the next line. Then `\Large` is executed which changes the font and current baselineskip (but not the value just stored) then the text `Wonerfull Title` is set. Then there is a newline so the saved vspace is added after that text.

similarly the large space after the date is the `\vspace{2\baselineskip}`   which was added in horizontal mode in that line so appears at the linebreak after the date.

You should almost always use a blank line (or `\par`) before `\vspace` so that it is added at the point it appears, also add a `\par` or blank line at each size change so that the current paragraph is set with a suitable baselineskip.

Comment: Thank you! Now the spacing finally makes sense to me! Before, it was somewhat strange and frankly annoying. 
The Insertions of \par don't really work since - for some reason I don't really understand - the document gives me an error, when I do that. But thats not that important since the approach of Simon Dispas answer works perfectly.

Comment: @Sinthoras yes (just) after `\centering`, ``\\`` uses `\par` internally so a `\vspace` after ``\\`` appears at that point (without the `\centering` it would again appear after the following line)